# How to save images drawn in Python turtle module that are outside screen area

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am new to Python. I wrote a Python code using turtle module, but when i am trying to save the image, the part of the image that is visible in the screen is only getting saved, the parts that are outside are getting cropped. I am saving using the following command:

```
turtle.getcanvas().postscript(file = "filename.eps")
```

I have also tried to resize the turtle screen using `turtle.screensize()` to make it bigger than the drawn image, but then also the part of the image that was saved was the part visible in the screen only.

Please help,

Comment: can you post the rest of your code, and the cropped out image?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height and width arguments.

```
turtle.getscreen().getcanvas().postscript(file='outputname.ps', height=10000,
width=10000)
```